# AWS PHP SDK : Add PATCH support to the Http/Client/Provider implementations

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, aws-sdk, lamp

I'm trying to install AWS PHP SDK on my EC2 instance using document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html

I'm  Installing via Composer.

While executing

```
php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

getting message to : Add PATCH support to the Http/Client/Provider implementations and then throwing error mentioned below:

```
Cannot apply patch https://bitbucket.org/twengg/gromit/raw/1.5.0/patches/phalcon/incubator/addHttpClientPatchSupport.patch
```

Kindly advise; how to fix this error.

Comment: Have you tried simple zip extraction?

Comment: @Justinas ; no not tried simple zip extraction yet. I am trying installing via composer.